# Как пишется (в)глубь парка?

Tags: предлоги, слитно-раздельно

Задано предложение: ***Витя ушел (в)глубь парка*** (вопрос с Мail.ru).

Ожидаемый ответ: ***в глубь парка***, но ведь есть еще наречный предлог: ***вглубь парка*** (такое написание встречается в Нацкорпусе).

Как выбрать правильное решение **для данного предложения** и обосновать его? А как подобрать **парный вариант** с другим написанием?

У меня есть определенная версия ответа, но мне хотелось бы узнать ваше мнение.
Если думаете так же, то принимаю ответ сразу. А если нет, то можно обсудить тему.

Answer (score 2):

Раздельно!

> Смотрим у Розенталя: "Наречия с пространственным и временнЫм значением,
> имеющие в своем составе существительные верх, низ, перед, зад, высь,
> даль, глубь, ширь, начало, конец, век: вверх, наверх, внизу, книзу,
> назад, ввысь, вдаль, вглубь, вширь, вконец, наконец, ввек, довеку,
> навеки пишутся слитно. Эти наречия пишутся раздельно только при
> наличии в предложении пояснительного слова к указанным
> существительным".

[Пишем наречия правильно](https://cbs-kstovo.ru/biblioblog/1369-pishem-narechia-pravilno.html)

---

[Чем глубь норы и страны принципиально отлична от глуби океана? с предлогом "в"?](https://otvet.mail.ru/question/91376183)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

У территорий (парков, садов, лесов) глубины нет. Здесь *вглубь* (*ушел вглубь парка*) не означает погружение на некую глубину.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Ну это смотря какой парк, лесопарк может занимать большую территорию. ГЛУБЬ,  ж. =Глубина (2, 4-5 зн.).  Глубина (глубь) может обозначать большую удалённость от края. Поэтому есть парные варианта: в глубь лес и вглубь леса.

Comment: Наречие *глубоко* более органично для таких сочетаний (зашёл глубоко), чем существительные (глубь, глубина, глубины).

Comment: С каждым днем приходилось забираться все дальше и дальше в глубь леса. [В. П. Астафьев. Васюткино озеро (2015)]  В Нацкорпусе  130 примеров. В этом предложении, как я думаю, правильный выбор. Парный вариант явно присутствует, но по каким признакам определяется нужное решение?

Answer (score 1):

**Комментарий по ответу**

Галина, большое спасибо за ответ))

Я тоже очень люблю и уважаю Розенталя, но время не стоит на месте. В настоящий момент **практика письма** ясно говорит о том, что существуют **две формы написания**: в глубь парка/леса и вглубь парка/леса, а также **много других парных вариантов** с пространственным значением (вглубь страны и в глубь страны и т.д.). Соответственно, очень важно **определить критерий**, по которому различаются эти варианты.

В правилах Розенталя используется **упрощенное** (формальное) решение, и в то время простота была понятна и нужна. Но для современных писателей, да и всего общества, это уже не столь важно, творческим людям нужно больше свободы – вероятно, они **интуитивно чувствуют разницу**. Поэтому школьный (более простой) вариант можно оставить, но указать, что в современной литературе возможно использование **наречного предлога "вглубь".**

Поэтому я приведу только информацию **по словарям** и статистику **по слитному
написанию** наречного предлога ***вглубь***.

**1. Словари**

**Орфографический словарь РАН:** **ВГЛУБЬ**, нареч. и предлог (распространиться вглубь и вширь; зверь забился вглубь норы), но сущ. в глубь (в глубь океана; в глубь веков; в глубь души; вникать в глубь, в суть проблемы)

**Большой толковый словарь (Кузнецова)**: ВГЛУБЬ, нареч. В глубину чего-л., внутрь. Продвинуться в. Распространяться в. и вширь.

**Толковый словарь Ефремовой**: ВГЛУБЬ нареч. обстоят. места [https://gufo.me/dict/efremova/вглубь](https://gufo.me/dict/efremova/%D0%B2%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B1%D1%8C)

По этой же ссылке есть данные о других словарях. **И вот что интересно**: у Ожегова и Ушакова также указано слитное написание наречного предлога, а в других словарях обозначено только наречие. Это значит, что **дискуссия по этому вопросу** велась постоянно.

В настоящий момент в толковых словарях **Ефремовой и Кузнецова** указано значение наречия, но наречный предлог «вглубь» обозначен **в орфографическом словаре РАН** (а это самые существенные и современные данные).

**2. Нацкорпус**

Перечень пространственных значений: **вглубь страны**, России, территории, тайги, двора, дома, квартиры, комнаты, автобуса; **вглубь космоса**, атома; **вглубь себя**, сознания, души, сердца.

*Быстрым шагом двинулся **вглубь парка**, стараясь реже ступать на снег и порой прыгая с проталины на проталину.* [Захар Прилепин. Санькя (2006)]

*Напротив статуи раскинула ветви молодая тонкая осина, недавно только пересаженная **вглубь парка***… [Дмитрий Лагутин. Спица // «Дальний Восток», 2019]

*Если от Эпсли-хаус двигаться **вглубь парка,** рано или поздно выйдете к озеру Серпентин и одноименной галерее Серпентин* (Serpentine Gallery). [Лондон (2006)]

*После самец издал резкий фыркающий лай, оскалился, щёлкнул зубами и вернулся к самке. И они спокойно ушли **вглубь леса**.* [А. Лесняк, Я. К. Бадридзе. Волк в человечьей шкуре, 2016]

*Лось уводил стрелка **вглубь леса,** на сквозной простор заветной поляны* [Борис Телков. Морока — морошка… // «Точка зрения», 2012]

*Уходящая далеко **вглубь леса** дорога делит изображение на две части, символика которых вполне очевидна...* [Т. Акимова. Музей истории искусства. Вена (2012)]